# Why is VSCode's Prettier Extension not working for Python?

Tags: python, formatting, vscode-extensions, prettier

Prettier won't format my python files. Help me what to do!

help me with this. I am using prettier and tried it. It worked well with javascript.[image]

Comment: I don't see python being supported - by [official](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html#official-plugins) or [community](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html#community-plugins) plugin.

Comment: is there any good extension for python formatting?

Answer (score 4):

Prettier doesn't officially support Python, you can use `autopep8` or `black` instead. You can either install their extension or install them for one specific directory by:

1. Open `.py` file on vscode
2. Right-click on it, and choose `Format document with...`
3. Select `Configure default formatter`
4. It should ask to install a few formatters for Python, choose whichever one you prefer

The process will start automatically, when it's completed it will format your Python code every time you save it.